# Is division inherently the last operation when using fraction notation or is the order of operation always PEMDAS?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, arithmetic

Are parenthesis needed when adding or subtracting in the dividend or divisor when using fraction notation to divide, or is it inherent that division is the last step using this notation?

$
X = \frac{n}{a - b + c}
\\or\\
X = \frac{n}{(a - b + c)}
$

Comment: $a - b +c$ is unambiguous so no parenthesis needed.  Nor would $(a-b+c)$ add any clarity.

Comment: That's a computer keyboard typing issue and has nothing whatsoever to do with mathematics.  The only problem with *typing*  X = n/a-b+c is we can not *see* that a-b+c are all supposed to be below the division bar.  In mathematics where no-one gives a dang whether you have a keyboard or are writing with feather quill and inkwell, it is assumed that you can write a-b+c under a line.  And if you can't, well, that's *your* problem, for you to figure out.  And if you *do* have a keyboard... well, then the only solution you have is to put parenthesis around a-b+c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if $$X = \frac{n}{a - b + c}$$ does not mean $$X = \frac{n}{(a - b + c)},$$ what could it mean? Could it possibly mean $$X = \frac{n}{a} - b + c?$$ If so, then you should just write *that*. There is ambiguity only when you must put everything on a single line, e.g., `X = n/(a - b + c)`, as you might, for instance, when programming a computer.

Answer (score 2):

Fraction notation always implies that the expressions above and below the fraction bar are completely evaluated before the division.  So for instance, $\frac{n+m}{a-b+c}$ always means $(n+m)\div(a-b+c)$.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Thanks!